# Toggle Navigation

Tags: jquery, toggle, slidetoggle

I'm trying to toggle the open navigation items(Insights, Campaigns, etc) closed if another is open. When one section is open, and the user clicks another, the existing open sections shoudl toggle closed. Only one section should be open at a time. Given the following HTML structure:

```
<li> <a href="#/insights" class="open_div"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i><span class="hidden-sm">Insights</span></a>
<ul>
            <li class="desc_div"><a class="submenu" href="#/insights/query"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i><span class="hidden-sm">Power Query</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="desc_div"><a class="submenu" href="#/insights/dashboards"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i><span class="hidden-sm">Dashboards</span></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li> <a class="dropmenu open_div" href="#campaigns"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i><span class="hidden-sm">Campaigns</span></a>

        <ul>
            <li class="desc_div"><a class="submenu" href="#/campaigns/orders"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i><span class="hidden-sm">Orders</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="desc_div"><a class="submenu" href="#/campaigns/assets"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i><span class="hidden-sm">Assets</span></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li> <a class="dropmenu" href="#inventory"><i class="fa fa-archive"></i><span class="hidden-sm">Inventory</span></a>

        <ul>
            <li><a class="submenu" href="#/inventory/properties"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i><span class="hidden-sm">Properties</span></a>
            </li>
            <li><a class="submenu" href="#/inventory/targeting"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i><span class="hidden-sm">Targeting Groups</span></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="#/accounts"><i class="fa fa-users"></i><span class="hidden-sm">Accounts</span></a>

        <ul>
            <li><a class="submenu" href="#/accounts/advertisers"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i><span class="hidden-sm">Advertisers</span></a>
            </li>
            <li><a class="submenu" href="#/accounts/publishers"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i><span class="hidden-sm">Publishers</span></a>
            </li>
            <li><a class="submenu" href="#/accounts/users"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i><span class="hidden-sm">Users</span></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li> <a class="dropmenu" href="#/administration"><i class="fa fa-cogs"></i><span class="hidden-sm">Administration</span></a>

        <ul>
            <li><a class="submenu" href="#/administration/user_roles"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i><span class="hidden-sm">User Roles</span></a>
            </li>
            <li><a class="submenu" href="#/administration/ad_types"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i><span class="hidden-sm">Ad Types</span></a>
            </li>
            <li><a class="submenu" href="#/administration/product_types"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i><span class="hidden-sm">Product Types</span></a>
            </li>
            <li><a class="submenu" href="#/administration/rate_types"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i><span class="hidden-sm">Rate Types</span></a>
            </li>
            <li><a class="submenu" href="#/administration/industry_verticals"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i><span class="hidden-sm">Industry Verticals</span></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
```

and jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".open_div").click(function(){
    $(".desc_div").toggle();
    $(this).next(".desc_div").slideToggle("slow").siblings('.desc_div').slideUp();
  });
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".open_div").click(function(){
        $(".desc_div:visible").toggle();
        $(this).next(".desc_div").slideToggle("slow").siblings('.desc_div').slideUp();
    });
})
```

Comment: That will just close the main nav elements, and keep them closed(disabling the navigation)